# Git: Simplify commit graph?

Tags: git

If I look at the commit graph with `gitk --all`, it's quite complicated (I did a lot of branching and merging just for the fun of it on a little one person project). Now I was wondering, if there is a way to simplify this graph?

Simplify in the sense of removing unnecessary branching (the branches are all merged into master at some point)

Comment: Simplify in what sense? Do you want to filter out certain commits? How was the graph too complicated for you?

Comment: Why is this off topic? Am asking how to do a specific thing?

Comment: The graph is not too complicated for me - I just wondered if git can simplify it because git has a lot of awesome features. Simplify in the sense of removing unnecessary branching (the branches are all merged into master at some point)

Comment: I haven't marked it as off topic, but you're *not* asking a specific question. You're not making it clear what you want to do; "simplify" is very vague.

Comment: @Alex: The question was for the ones voting to close this question - would be nice to know why and have a change to elaborate.

Comment: Could be considered off topic for SO as it doesn't relate to coding (git is often used as a code tracker, but using git itself is not coding). Superuser might be better suited.

Comment: Well, there is a much used git-tag here as well as some other git (but not specifically programming) related tags...

Comment: @Alex: No, no, no, absolutely not. Git and other VCSes have been established as on topic for years. Search for [git]. And then look at the [faq], which mention "software tools commonly used by programmers" as one of the four primary categories of questions.

Comment: My apologies, was only trying to find reasons why others would mark as off topic. I have no problem with it.

Comment: @Alex: Sorry for calling you out a bit harshly. I've seen this crop up again and again, so I tend to try to quash it quickly - especially since this had somehow already accumulated 3 close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that what you're looking for is the first parent option, which causes Git to walk to only the first parent of merge commits as it traverses the history. You can use it from the command line:

```
git log --first-parent
gitk --first-parent
```

or within gitk: View > New view... > Limit to first parent (under Miscellaneous).

Of course, you might also *not* want to use `--all`; `gitk <commit>...` shows only the history starting from the given commits (which could be specified as branches), and with no arguments it defaults to the current branch.

If you have a more precise idea about the history you want to see, you could use some of the other options listed under History Simplification in `man git-log`. Notably there's `--ancestry-path` which can be used to show only the direct ancestry path: `git log --ancestry-path commit1..commit2`. `gitk` generally takes the same commit specification options as `git-log`, which inherits them in turn from `git-rev-list`.

Comment: History Simplification in man git-log was a good hint - that's what I meant by simplification. Now, is there a way to not only show the simplified graph, but to simplify the graph itself? git rebase is obviously rewriting the history and commits, so maybe something similar is possible?

Comment: @mort: That sounds like a very different question. If you actually want to rewrite history, throughout your entire repository, `git filter-branch` is perhaps what you want. If you want to just do it on recent history, `git rebase -i` might be what you want. All the usual caveats about rewriting apply: don't do it if this has been pushed or otherwise shared with anyone. If that's not enough of a hint, edit your question or post a different question with a clearer notion of what you're trying to accomplish, since this one seems to be about simplifying the view.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints. I know this was a rather unspecific question - just wanted to find out what git could do without having a concrete problem in mind

Answer (score 1):

When you want to take a look of entire history, **--all** could be too much. Here is some options that could give you a hand of what's cooking on a repo:

```
git --simplify-by-decoration --all
gitk --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

It will show all commits "marked" with a ref or tag, included those not marked needed to understand ancestry (pretty useful). See [git log history simplification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Answering your exact questions you can use:

```
git --simplify-merges --all
gitk --simplify-merges --all
```

but that is included on **--simplify-by-decoration**

I make a lot use of that (on command line) so I use an alias:

```
git config --global alias.logs 'log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --color --oneline --decorate'
```

To use it:

```
git logs --all
git logs master..development
```